# When building a regression in python how do I assign greater weight to more recent data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am using historical data to predict car accident costs. I don't want to completely ignore older data, but I would like to weigh more recent data as more important when training the model. I plan on trying several sklearn regressors such as linear regression and random forest regression, is there a way to incorporate this concept into a sklearn model?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. sklearn's `LinearRegression` class supports weights for samples. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you!
I haven't built the model yet, I was first trying to figure out how the weighting would be possible. If I have a column which is the number of years passed since the accident, how do I convert that into a value which can be passed in as an appropriate weight so that the greater the number of years the smaller the weight?

Comment: Use `sample_weight` param in a `.fit()` method. See [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236836/weighted-linear-regression-with-scikit-learn) for explanation,

Comment: @tshwizz did you figure out the solution? how to give the sample weight based on date?